# Cannot view sql server agent in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have installed full setup of SQL Server, and start the service for SQL Agent through SQL Server surface area. But still I can't get SQL Agent tree node in my SQL Server connection treeview.

So please help me what I have to do for getting SQL Agent in treeview.

Comment: Do you have the permissions to see it?  SSMS lets me connect to the database see the tree; but unless the DBA granted me privileges, I couldn't see it either.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum rights needed to see the agent node you need to have sysadmin rights on the instance or rights to the agent database roles in msdb.

Comment: And an edition above Express

Comment: Thought about that, but he said he got the agent started, and the SQLEXPRESS agent instance defaults to disabled and doesn't start properly if you try to change the type.